# Detect SQL dialect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know which SQL dialect is being used in the snippet. Is it MSSQL, MySQL, PL/SQL or is it invalid SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE ACTable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    x float NOT NULL,
    y float NOT NULL,
    z float NOT NULL
)
CONSTRAINT [PK_FTTable] PRIMARY KEY( id )
```

Comment: what you mean dialect?

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza dialect refers to the syntax differences between different DBMS. It can also refer to sql that only works in a given DBMS.

Comment: This is invalid SQL code

Comment: @SeanLange No, i have this code, and I don't know where it's from.

Comment: @daron . . . The square braces suggest T-SQL which is most strongly associated with SQL Server, but also used by Sybase (and accepted by SQLite).  However, the code is invalid.

Comment: Where did you get the code? It is reasonably close to valid syntax for more than 1 DBMS. If you replaced the ) in the create table with a comma and added a closing ) at the end it would be valid in sql server, sybase and sqlite. The [] is typically sql server so that would be my guess.

Comment: @SeanLange This code comes from homework. It can be invalid. (Maybe it's like pseudoCode).

Comment: It's from your homework and you are asking us which DBMS it is for? Maybe it should be in your notes? Or maybe based on the class you are taking?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, there aren't precisely described what DBMS it is. All homework code is in Java language. It's not very important to know, I thought that it's not pseudoCode :)

Comment: @Daron, it is always important to know what database backend you are accessing. The syntax varies for different backends. You wouldn't say it wasn't important to know if the application code was written in C# or Java would you? It is just as important to know what flavor of SQL you are writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL is incorrect but this SQL would work in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    x float NOT NULL,
    y float NOT NULL,
    z float NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_FTTable] PRIMARY KEY( id ))
```

Answer (score 1):

This part is OK in almost every rdbms

```
CREATE TABLE ACTable (
    id int NOT NULL,
    x float NOT NULL,
    y float NOT NULL,
    z float NOT NULL
)
```

The problem is the constraint, and doesnt look like a valid statment for any db.

You can try that `CREATE TABLE` on every rdmbs on **[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not valid SQL.

Every database that I can think of requires an `alter table . . .` for adding a constraint.

Of course, there are databases I can't readily think of.  But I go with it is just an error.  After all, there is no context for the table affected by the constraint.